# Android - mount OBB in service

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm writing an application which includes a service and mounts an OBB file from service. 
I'm referring this documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/StorageManager.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/storage/OnObbStateChangeListener.html

However, onObbStateChange() callback never happens.

If I use the very same code in application's activity, it successfully mounts and I get access to the internals of the OBB file.

Below is the code snippet:

```
// Extend OnObbStateChangeListener class
public class MyService extends Service {
  static StorageManager storageManager;

  static class Observer extends OnObbStateChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
      Log.v(TAG, path + " " + state); // 1
    }
  }
}

// Mount obb
public void getMountedPath() {
  File file = new File("<path to obb file>");
  if(!obbFile.exists())
    return;
  Observer observer = new Observer();
  boolean state = storageManager.mountObb(obbFile.getAbsolutePath(), null, obbObserver);
  Log.v(TAG, "state: " + state); // 2 It always prints TRUE
}
```

Any idea why it's not able to mount from my service class?

**More observations:**

When I execute the app for the first time, I get mount state as TRUE in the second log statement and onObbStateChange() doesn't get invoked.

However, when I run my app second time, I see the first log from onObbStateChange() and it prints state as 24 which means ERROR_ALREADY_MOUNTED.

So it seems that the obb got mounted in the first attempt, however, onObbStateChange() didn't get invoked for some reason.

Any explanations on this behavior?

Comment: You seem to be missing the code where you attempt to mount the obb and register the receiver

Comment: @ChrisStratton please see the edits.